# Api Platform/Symfony and PHPUnit - How to inject a Service into an ApiTestCase (multiple constructor arguments)

Tags: symfony, phpunit, autowired, code-injection, api-platform.com

I have a BaseClass that extends the ApiTestCase of PHPUnit.
Now in order to generate the Endpoint-URLs, I would like to be able to get the IRI of a given Entity, so, naive as I am, I tried to **autowire** the IriConverter into the BaseClass.

This throws an error, because autowiring does not detect the first argument to be an injected service. Also tried to manually define the **$conv** argument to be the **api_platform.iri_converter** in the services.yaml.

```
    public function __construct(IriConverter $conv, ?string $name = null, array $data = [], $dataName = '')
    {
        parent::__construct($name, $data, $dataName);
        $this->iriConverter = $conv;
     }
```

I do not know if **Api Platform** has a faulty Setter-Injection integration, but this is not working either. I also tried manually calling that function by declaring the "call" property of that Service in services.yaml, but no luck.

```
    /** @required */
    public function setConverter(IriConverter $conv): void
    {
        $this->iriConverter = $conv;
    }
```

Due to the **IriConverter** being inlined or removed when the container is compiled, this is not working either. Rather it is recommended to inject the service in the constructor, but how do I do that?

```
    public function setUp(): void
    {
        self::bootKernel();

        $this->iriConverter = self::$kernel->getContainer()->get('api_platform.iri_converter');

        // this right here throws a ServiceNotFound Exception - "The "kernel" service is synthetic, it needs to be set at boot time before it can be used."
        // $this->iriConverter = self::$container->get('api_platform.iri_converter');
    }
```

Thank you for reading this far!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I found a solution.

The issue lies with fetching the IriConverter-Service inside the setUp()-function, because at this point the kernel is still booting, so no container is available.

I use the IriConverter only in one function and it looks like this:

```php
    protected function getEntityIri(): string {
        if (!$this->iriConverter) {
            $this->iriConverter = self::$container->get(IriConverterInterface::class);
        }
        return $this->iriConverter->getIriFromResourceClass($this->getEntityClass());
    }
```

The IriConverter is fetched from the container on demand.
This solution is somewhat obscure, because Dependency Injection on instantiation or Setter-Injection is usually hailed as the correct way to do it, but maybe that is just my perception. Maybe the reason lies with using the PHPUnit Test environment?

Anyways, marked as solved

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to boot the kernel manually, it is done automatically when using `self::getContainer()`. I have this in one of my Symfony 5.4 tests.

```
use ApiPlatform\Core\Api\IriConverterInterface;

private IriConverterInterface $iriConverter;

protected function setUp(): void
{
    $this->iriConverter = self::getContainer()->get(IriConverterInterface::class);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The getContainer()-function does not exist in the ApiTestCase-Class. But I tried using the static container by calling self::$container->get(IriConverterInterface::class) but $container is null. So then I call self::bootKernel() right before calling the container, but that leads to a "ServiceNotFoundException" with the message "The "kernel" service is synthetic, it needs to be set at boot time before it can be used."

Comment: All this logic is happening inside the setUp()-function. Ill have to read up on container and kernel lifecycle, because it seems a kernel exists, but no container...?

Comment: Also, when calling "self::$kernel->getContainer()->get(IriConverterInterface::class)" I get the "Service has been inlined or removed when the container was compiled" Error again.